# Php, preg_match letter with two signs

Tags: php

I have four letters l, j, lj, nj. Problem is in the `preg_match_all` becouse letter "lj" or "nj" can be count if string contains only "j" or "l" or "n"....

How to count them like one letter?

Comment: Please paste your code

Comment: one simple fix is to just include all possible combinations in an "or" list like `(lj|nj|l|j)`. They are evaluated left to right so that when one is found, that is the match. Make the larger length strings come before the smaller ones.

Comment: hungry coder needs code to chew on!